# Trying to connect to mongoDB on EC2 via terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to connect to MongoDB running on EC2 via terminal(ssh). 
I have changed the `bind_ip` from the mongodb.conf to `0.0.0.0` 
I am still unable to connect.

```
sudo mongo admin --username --password
```

This is the error that I am receiving. I am new to this, I don't know what I should be doing to connect.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017/admin
2015-11-25T09:36:46.604+0000 E QUERY    Error: 18 Authentication failed.
    at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1271:32)
    at (auth):6:8
    at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1271
exception: login failed
```

Thank you.